# TeamCity, version numbers from file in repo and assembly patcher

Tags: powershell, teamcity, version

#### Context

In our repo, we have a file called `version.txt` that contains the major and minor version number: `0.7`.

I added a TeamCity build step with a powershell script that sets this parameter into a config parameter, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23449706/1591992):

```
$version = Get-Content version.txt
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='UserMajorDotMinor' value='$version']"
```

The `UserMajorDotMinor` parameter defaults to `0.6` on TeamCity.

I have a config parameter called `%UserVersionNumber%` that is used to set the actual version number, which is defined as

```
%UserMajorDotMinor%.0.%system.build.number%
```

### The Problem

While prints `0.7` in the TeamCity build log, but it doesn't seem to properly set the UserVersionNumber, because the number that the assembly patcher writes into the dll is still `0.6.0.xxxxx`.

What do I have to change so TeamCity will actually write the correct version number into the dlls?

Comment: The Assembly patcher will run before any build step, therefore, changes made to parameters within a step won´t reflect in the Assembly Info Patcher.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [TeamCity - AssemblyInfoPatcher not working, error is logged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938529).

Comment: Not really a duplicate, even if the solutions are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Assembly Info Patcher build feature will run *before* any build step, therefore, changes made to parameters within a step won´t affect the Assembly Info Patcher

If you really need to use the Major.Minor Info from the version.txt file then i would setup a seperate build configuration that reads the file and provides the content as build parameter `%UserMajorDotMinor%`. Basicly what you already did.

Then you can add the newly created config as dependency to the actual build and set the `%Version%` Parameter to `%dep.[buildconfigname].UserMajorDotMinor%.0.%system.build.number%`

As a Alternative, use a Script to patch your AssemblyInfo.cs files as seperate build step instead of the Assembly Info Pather Feature.